# how to remove resizing from cocoa autolayout

Tags: cocoa, autolayout

I'm trying to get an NSBox to maintain it's width and height as well as staying centered in it's section of a split view. How can I use InterfaceBuilder to set the box to not resize and still use auto layout? Or, do I have to update the constraints programmatically?

[Sample File](http://www.filedropper.com/accountsview)

It appears the "pin" that jrturton suggested works if the box isn't in a split view. You can just open the xib in Xcode and click Editor->Simulate Document to see the 2 examples.

[Sample File - Revision 1](http://www.filedropper.com/accountsview_1)

[Solution](http://www.filedropper.com/accountsview_2): I had to add an extra NSView to the split view that held the NSBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your box, then use the Pin... menu:

[image: Pin menu]

The Width and Height options allow you to add constraints for a constant size. You can also add centring constraints here. Once you've added these, you can delete any other constraints IB has added, if it doesn't do so automatically for you.

Comment: When I pin the height, the entire window's height get pinned as well.

Comment: I should also note that I added a new sample file to my question. It appears the pin you suggested works if the box isn't in a split view. You can just open the xib in Xcode and click Editor->Simulate Document to see the 2 examples. Do you have any suggestions on how to get the height pinned without pinning the window's height?

Answer (score 0):

In IB, click on the file inspector (The first icon), then make sure auto layout is not checked.

[image]
<sub>(source: [fredandrandall.com](http://fredandrandall.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/saveasautolayout.png))</sub>

Then go to the size inspector (The 5th icon) and make sure the autosizing is set to as following.

[image]
<sub>(source: [smallsharptools.com](http://www.smallsharptools.com/downloads/Stackoverflow/autosizing-off.png))</sub>

Comment: Close but not quite what I was looking for. I want that same affect but I still want to use auto layout.